# Scheduling a Task On A Remote Machine

Tags: winapi

I am trying to use Microsoft's Task Scheduler to schedule a task on a remote machine. I am getting the {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) error. I am running the code as an admin in an elevated state. I remember reading before that a user trying to work with the task scheduler on a remote machine must be a member of a specific group. I do not remember the group name. It's not the administrators group. Can someone help ? I am doing this on a domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Control Panel, open "Administrative Tools", then "Local Security Policy".
2. Locate "Security Settings", open "Local Policies" and select "User Rights Assignment".
3. Find "Log on as a batch Job". Open the properties and add any users that need this right.

I hope I used the correct English Translation.